# Using my own alternate images to those in the "SpriteKit with Swift" Tutorial in Xcode 7 Swift 2 Project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I am fairly new to programming and, as such, am still in the follow-the-tutorials stage of coding. Specifically, my most recent undertaking is "SpriteKit with Swift" (had to delete this link because I don't have 10 reputation)
Anyway, my issues lie with images. I have been doing everything else in accordance with the tutorial, but I wanted to use my own images for the SpriteNodes instead of the satellite and asteroid. Additionally, I want to set a specific image as my background, but every time I go about that I see that image alone in the Simulator. I just don't want to make the game verbatum; I want my own twist.

I am using Swift 2 in Xcode 7

Thanks in advance

[this is what came up whilst I was putting in the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPhQZ.png)
[this is what my GameScene looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvmVg.png)

Comment: So you can see the background image you've supplied in the simulator but not when you've deployed your application to a device?

Also, it'd be cool to see what you've tried thus far, as it's difficult to assist you if we havn't got any code to look at.

Comment: We need to see some code to know whats going on.

Comment: My bad. I am new to Stack Overflow. I will add some screenshots of code first thing tomorrow

Comment: _Do not_ add screenshots of your code. Add the code itself. Add _only_ as much code is needed to illustrate your problem. But before you do that, read [ask], since you're new here and clearly didn't read any of that the first time around.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  I up-voted your question because I think it is a good one, but I do agree you should add code and more detail :)

Answer (score 2):

Always try to post code when using stack overflow. I am not 100% sure this is what you are asking but Ill give it a shot.

By default SpriteKit optimises how it adds sprites.

```
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true // in gameViewController
```

This should stay true most likely because it optimises SpriteKits performance. It basically means sprites will not always get added to the SKScene in the order you are adding them to the scene.

You need to start using zPosition when layering multiple images in a scene with a defined order.

To add a background you would do this

```
let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "image name in asset catalogue"
background.zPosition = 1 // 1st layer
background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
addChild(background)
```

To add sprites on top of the background you would do this

```
let sprite1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "image name in asset catalogue"
sprite1.zPosition = 2 // above background
sprite1.position = ...
addChild(sprite1)

let sprite2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "image name in asset catalogue"
sprite2.zPosition = 2 // if 3 also above sprite 1
sprite2.position = ...
addChild(sprite2)
```

I presume this is whats causing your problem, you are adding a background but the sprites after are not visible because they are below the background.